# C#, Validating user input for letters and whitespace using boolean

Tags: c#, input, while-loop, boolean

I'm making a program that reverses a string and doesn't allow for anything else than letters and whitespaces, problem is that if i enter a non-valid input and then try to input a valid input it just keeps printing error. I think the problem has something to do with my while loop and the bool result, but i can't figure it out. Please help and thank you!

```
        static void Reverse()
        {
            string name;
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            bool result = name.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetter(c));
            if (Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[a-zA-Z- ]+$"))  // Validates the input for characters and/or spaces
            {
                char[] charArr = name.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(charArr);
                string nameRev = new string(charArr);
                Console.WriteLine("String is {0}", nameRev);
            }
            else
            {
                while (name == String.Empty || result == false) //Should validate the input for whitespace or letter if it doesn't pass the first validation
                {
                    Console.Write("Error! Enter your name, only letters allowed: ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

Comment: The problem is that you never set result to true in the while loop so if the first Iteration is not correct you never leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your while loop around the hole sequence instead of just having it inside the else statement.

**Example:**

```cs
static void Reverse()
{
    // Continues executing as long as result stays false.
    bool result;
    do 
    {
        string name;
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        result = name.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetter(c));
        if (Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[a-zA-Z- ]+$"))
        {
            char[] charArr = name.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArr);
            string nameRev = new string(charArr);
            Console.WriteLine("String is {0}", nameRev);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! Only letters allowed");
        }
    }
    while (!result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i see the problem now, i'll keep trying to figure out my own solution!